# Storing values from webpage with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a dictionary that stores the values from one class as keys, and another class as it's values from the webpage I'm working on.

Here's what I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

all_data = []
for i in range(1, 5, 1):
    url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/cristiano-ronaldo/profil/spieler/'+str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = {}
    market_left = soup.find('div', {'class':'right-td'})
    market_right = soup.find('div', {'class':'left-td'})
for m in market_left:
    for mr in market_right:
        print(data[m.text.strip()].append(mr.text.strip()))
```

However I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Also when I increase the number in the range so say for example from `range(1, 10, 1)`, It doesn't seem to iterate over many pages, it only selects the last one. Any idea on how it can grab the information for each page within the loop?

Expected output :

```
{'Current market value:':[-, -, -,-,-]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `zip` in python to iterate over two list simultaneously.

Try like below:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    url = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/silvio-adzic/profil/spieler/{}".format(i)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
    market_left = soup.find_all('div',class_="left-td")
    market_right = soup.find_all('div',class_="right-td")
    print(f"In Page {i}")
    for l,r in zip(market_left,market_right):
        l_value = l.text.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
        r_value = r.text.replace('\n','').replace(' ','')
        print(f"{l_value} {r_value}")
        # Code to add the details to dictionary.
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------")
```

And few of the pages dint have the data you are looking for.

```
In Page 1
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Apr23,2009
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £225Th.Oct4,2004
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 2
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 3
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 4
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Feb13,2007
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £360Th.Oct4,2004
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 5
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Sep14,2010
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £1.26mOct4,2004
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 6
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Aug2,2010
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £765Th.Oct6,2005
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 7
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Jan30,2014
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £1.08mOct4,2004
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 8
Currentmarketvalue: -
Lastupdate: Jan2,2010
Highestmarketvalue:Lastupdate: £1.35mJun2,2006
-----------------------------------------------------------
In Page 9
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Why do I get an error when I try storing the values within a dictionary like this: ```data[l_value].append(r_value)``` at the end of your script. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Stackcans - `data` is a dictionary. `add`, `append`, `insert` methods doesn't work. You need to collect the `values` - `r-value` separately in a list and then assign those values to the respective key - `l-value`